# Entity Framework Core set maximum depth

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am working on a database first approach to a web api and I unfortunately have self-referencing loops all over the place. I was wondering if there was a way to set the maximum depth when using entity framework to return a context.

For instance, if I had an Employee and Project relation where the Employee has a Projects field and the Project class has an employee field. I'd like to set a depth of (1) lets say that would return me the employees project objects but inside those project fields, the employee fields can be left blank.

If I run as it goes now, my browser stops everything when I hit a maximum depth of 32.

Comment: Are you using Lazy Loading? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: Yes I am using lazy loading. The problem is that I want "Employee -> Projects" but not "Employee -> Projects --> Employee --> Projects ... .... ...". If there was a way to just set the depth, that would be perfect

Comment: You really don’t want to use Lazy Loading for entities you are serializing as an API result.

Comment: Without lazy loading, I only get back the results from a single table. If I turn it on, then I get the infinite self referencing loop. Do you know of a way to meet somewhere in the middle. Use lazyloading but only go a depth of 1 outwards, only grab the first object basically.

Comment: Use Eager Loading or Explicit Loading to specify the shape of the Entity graph you want to serialize.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading